# Laravel grouped sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to reproduce the following MySQL query with Laravel:

```
SELECT SUM(distance) FROM trips WHERE user_id = 1 AND distance IS NOT NULL GROUP BY TRANSPORT
```

When I execute it in phpMyAdmin, I get the following result: 642778, 0, 1. Here's my attempt with Laravel:

```
$sortedDistances = Trip::where('user_id', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('distance')
    ->groupBy('transport')
    ->sum('distance');
```

When I `var_dump($sortedDistances)`, all I get is `string(6) "642778"`. Why isn't this an array?

Comment: No need to provide whereNotNull('distance') as sum(null)=0

Comment: Yeah but by skipping null lines doesn't it go an fraction of a millisecond faster? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you an array.

```
$sortedDistances = Trip::where('user_id', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('distance')
    ->select('transport', DB::raw('sum(distance) as TotalDistance'))
    ->groupBy('transport')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it does. I guess I've just discovered one of the limits of using an ORM…